# Exploring curl of a gradient of a scalar function

Tags: expression-manipulation, hold, vector-calculus

Suppose I want to explore  $\nabla \times \nabla V$ where $V$ is some scalar function. It basically results in a zero. But I would only know why if I solve it on paper. I wanted to use Mathematica for it and I have found some solutions but I want something cleaner.

```
pdConv[
  Curl[{Subscript[f, x][x, y, z], Subscript[f, y][x, y, z], Subscript[f, z][x, y, z]}, 
  {x, y, z}
  ] /. {Subscript[f, x] -> Defer[D[V, x]],
        Subscript[f, y] -> Defer[D[V, y]],      
        Subscript[f, z] -> Defer[D[V, z]]}
]
```

This gives this output:

[image: pretty-printed output]

I did have to do some unpleasant hackery and the other simpler attempt is

```
pdConv[Curl[{Hold[D[V[x, y, z], x]], 
Hold[D[V[x, y, z], y]], 
Hold[D[V[x, y, z], z]]}, {x, y, z}]]
```

This gives this output

[image: output containing explicit Hold]

which is just perfect, but I don't like the `Hold` appearing in the output and `HoldForm`,`Inactivate`,`Inactive` give weird stuff.

I have copied a function called `pdConv` [from the Wolfram Blog](https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/15/mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting/) that converts partial differential expressions to `TraditionalForm`. It is really helpful. Here is its definition:

```
pdConv[f_] := TraditionalForm[f /. Derivative[inds__][g_][vars___] :> 
(Defer[D[g[vars],##1]] & ) @@ (Transpose[{{vars}, {inds}}] /. {{var_, 0} :> 
Sequence[], {(var_)*1} :> {var}})]
```

What would be some more cleaner approaches?

Comment: Not sure why you need all this machinery: `Curl[Grad[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]` returns `{0, 0, 0}` directly. You can also apply `pdConv` to the intermediate result of `Grad`, but I would not do computation of the results of `*Form` functions, as those are output wrappers only ("pretty-printers").

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to tweak a system option, you can do this to make HoldForm be treated the same Hold by differentiation code:

```
SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions" -> 
    Append[
        SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions"][[-1, -1, -1, -1]],
        HoldForm
    ]
]
```

You can now use your code with `HoldForm` instead of `Hold`.  I'm a bit surprised that `HoldForm` isn't in that list by default.  I'll see about adding it to get it to format as you want.